# Will this Graphic Card run on my +12V / 18A PSU?

Tags: power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card

I am going to buy a Graphic card for my pc, but i dont know about my PSU if it can handle this GPU or not. My PSU SPECS are : +3.3V/15A, +5V/15A, +12V/18A, +5VSB/2A, -12V/ 0.8A, COM/Return, PS-ON/Remote
[image]
I dont know what these number says, maybe some voltage stuff..

this is my PSU link : http://www.beyondtime.in/Desktops-iball-SPS-252-bt

And Graphic Card that I am going to Buy is one of them, (links here)

GT 1030 : https://www.amazon.in/GIGABYTE-GeForce-GV-N1030D5-2GL-Computer-Graphics/dp/B071DY2VJR?tag=googinhydr18418-21

GT 730 :https://www.amazon.in/ZOTAC-GeForce-Zone-Graphics-Card/dp/B00R5UW038?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=7e089ccc-8611-4236-a159-733f15301443
my computer specs are:

Processor i3 3210
6GB RAM
500 Hard Disk
250 GB SSD
1DVD W/R

please suggest..

Comment: Impossible to answer without details about the rest of the computer. We can not know what amount of power the rest of the computer will be using.

Comment: ok wait, i will update question

Comment: please check now

Comment: I went ahead and answered this question.  However, hardware recommendations are out of scope, so I will NOT recommend any specific brand of PSU.  Try avoiding generic brands, your current PSU, is absolutely horrible.

Comment: @Ramhound You're right, those iBall PSU's are really mediocre quality. They are well-known to not being able to deliver their rated maximum. The 230W model isn't stable above approx. 180W and the 300W model won't do much above 250W. Luckily the rest of the computer doesn't need much. If the poster is dead-set on an iBall PSU a 400W model would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am going to buy a Graphic card for my pc, but i don't know about my
>   PSU if it can handle this GPU or not.

You currently have a 230 Watt PSU.

- The GT 1030 has a minimum suggested requirement of 300 Watts.
- The GT 730 has a minimum suggested requirement of 300 Watts.

> please suggest..

Upgrade to a 300+ Watt PSU.